# Any text editors for Mac with hotkey PASTE of pre-defined text for faster coding?

Tags: macos, text-editor, textedit

Coding PHP on a Mac using TextEdit. It's always annoying to have to type the same lines of code that I use over and over (`Ex: MyClass::myLocalizedString('Hello');`).

Anyone know of a useful editor for Mac that can save me time by allowing me to predefine a string and bind it to a hotkey combination?

`Ex: Cmd+1 pastes the text MyClass::myLocalizedString('');`

Comment: Did you try a full-blown IDE like NetBeans or Zend Studio? See here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/02/11/the-big-php-ides-test-why-use-oneand-which-to-choose/

Comment: BBEdit/TextWrangler have "text factories" and "clippings', Xcode has "clippings", TextMate has "snippets", all of which do what you want, I believe. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tincta Pro](http://mr-fridge.de/software/tincta) also has a code-snippets feature with shortcut expansion.

(Disclaimer: I'm the developer of Tincta)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are plenty of choises. For instance, you can use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com) to create a hotkey or use [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/) for short snippet. I think you might be able to create this with [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com) too, but for this I'm not sure.